# How do I format a Mac SSD drive in Linux Mint 20?

Tags: linux, filesystems, gparted

I have a 1 TB SSD drive that was taken from a Mac computer. I would like to use this drive in my Linux Mint 20 system or even in Windows 10. Based on information I found on this forum, I did "lsblk" and "Gparted" but I don't know what to do next. Truth be told, I am afraid to proceed without the guidance of a knowledgeable person.I have included the "lsblk" and "gparted" Terminal outputs below. Can someone please walk me through what I should do next? Just so you know, I know next to nothing about these things but I am good at following instructions.

Thanks and kind regards

Lsblk and Gparted Terminal outputs:

```
veganist@linux20:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   200M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0 930.7G  0 part 
└─sda3   8:3    0 619.9M  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sdb2   8:18   0   1.8T  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

```
veganist@linux20:~$ gparted
Unit boot.mount does not exist, proceeding anyway.
Unit tmp.mount does not exist, proceeding anyway.
GParted 1.0.0
configuration --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize
libparted 3.3
```

[Image of Gparted terminal input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEBzy.png)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to your problem is to reformat the disk to another filesystem as support for AFS is not that common among Linux and impossible with windows. If you are only going to use the drive in Linux, ext4 will be your best choice. Yet, if you want to use it in windows as well, you should use NTFS or exfat (if you also want to use it on a mac). After you have selected your filesystem start Gparted and go to your disk (in your screenshot it is /dev/sda) and remove all partitions on the disk and add a new partition with the specified fs type and any name you choose. And lastly apply the changes. **Your data on the disk will be lost! Please copy any important data away from the drive before reformatting.**

Cheers

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I however have some questions if you don't mind.

“After you have selected your file system start Gparted and go to your disk (in your screenshot it is /dev/sda) and remove all partitions on the disk and add a new partition with the specified fs type and any name you choose. And lastly apply the changes.” 

1. How do I select my file system?
2. How do I remove and add partitions?

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Veganist Those are entirely new questions. It's recommend to read the help of the software you intend to use for the purpose and, prior to that, understand what you want to do and why because you're showing below basic knowledge of the subject. WHY do you want to format the drive? The typical scenarios were already answered here with the recommend file systems. Using Gparted the easiest way to delete everything (and start over) is Device > Create new partition table... > select "GPT" (this will delete everything!), then right-click the now unallocated space and add a partition.